# Is there a way to add menu items programmatically from my component in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, menu, custom-component

I want to add standard joomla menu items via programmatic way that related a component. Is there a api way to add menu items or just only SQL way. I can add menu items via SQL way but some problems appear after that. 
We can create a menu and link menu items to my Joomla component items from joomla administrator. But I want to add menu and menu items to my component programmatically not to manually. For example I will make a button in my component edit. When we press it, menu items are created automatically.

Comment: Looks like this thread solves it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651075/programatically-create-menu-item-in-joomla

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a menu item for your component, that is automatically created from the components XML configuration file, if you want to add additional items as a submenu then JSubMenuHelper is probably what you're looking for.

They are discussed in [this section of the tutorial on creating components](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_12).

Comment: I am not meaning to create component menu on admin panel. I am meaning a standard menu on frontend. I want to create menu items that related components items that we add from admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JMenu api available in joomla for getting menuitems

http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JMenu/getItems

you can read this to refer to the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $menuTable = JTable::getInstance('Menu', 'JTable', array());

        $menuData = array(
        'menutype' => 'client-pages',
        'title' => $data[name],
        'type' => 'component',
        'component_id' => 22,                  
        'link' => 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$resultID,
        'language' => '*',
        'published' => 1,
        'parent_id' => '1',
        'level' => 1,
    );

    // Bind data
    if (!$menuTable->bind($menuData))
    {
        $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
        return false;
    }

    // Check the data.
    if (!$menuTable->check())
    {
        $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
        return false;
    }

    // Store the data.
    if (!$menuTable->store())
    {
        $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
        return false;
    }

    $db   = $this->getDbo();
    $qry = "UPDATE `#__menu` SET `parent_id` = 1 , `level` = 1 WHERE `id` = ".$menuTable->id;
    $db->setQuery($qry);
    $db->query();
```