# Create menu item in joomla programmatically

Tags: joomla

I've created a Joomla 3 component that will add some menu items programmatically. I've searched how to do it and I found this old question/answer:
[Programmatically Create Menu Item in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651075/programatically-create-menu-item-in-joomla?lq=1)

It suggest to use this code:

```
//add the article to a menu item
$menuTable = JTable::getInstance('Menu', 'JTable', array());

    $menuData = array(
    'menutype' => 'client-pages',
    'title' => $data[name],
    'type' => 'component',
    'component_id' => 22,                  
    'link' => 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$resultID,
    'language' => '*',
    'published' => 1,
    'parent_id' => '1',
    'level' => 1,
);

// Bind data
if (!$menuTable->bind($menuData))
{
    $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
    return false;
}

// Check the data.
if (!$menuTable->check())
{
    $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
    return false;
}

// Store the data.
if (!$menuTable->store())
{
    $this->setError($menuTable->getError());
    return false;
}
```

It works but have the same problem as shown on the question I linked.
    Showing the error: Warning: str_repeat() [function.str-repeat]: Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0 in .....

And someone suggest this solution I can't understand.

> Try using JTableNested::setLocation($referenceId, $position = 'after'):
>
> $table->setLocation($parent_id, 'last-child');
>   I also think that you need to rebuild the path:
>
> // Rebuild the tree path.
>   if (!$table->rebuildPath($table->id)) {
>       $this->setError($table->getError());
>       return false;
>   }

Could someone explain me where to use that solution?